# How can I receive incoming SIP calls when app is closed in IOS (Linphone)?

Tags: ios, swift, sip, callkit, linphone

In my SIP app, I integrated Linphone to it. I can do outgoing calls and receive incoming calls successfully when app is open, but but as a new feature, I want to be able to receive this call when the application is closed. I researched some documentations and I found out Callkit and Pushkit might work for this aim. But I dont know when someone calls me how can I trigger this incoming call in background. I followed the github issue below, but it didn't help.

https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-iphone/issues/612

You can look how did I integrate Pushkit and Callkit to my codes.

```
import UIKit
import CallKit
import PushKit

class SplashScreen : UIViewController, CXProviderDelegate, PKPushRegistryDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var logoHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var logoWidthConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var launcherIcon: UIImageView!
    
    private var registeredToBackgroundEvents = false
    
    let TAG = "SplashScreen"

    /// register to back from backround event
    private func registerToBackFromBackground() {
        if(!registeredToBackgroundEvents) {
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
            selector: #selector(viewDidBecomeActive),
            name: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)
            registeredToBackgroundEvents = true
        }
    }

    /// unregister from back from backround event
    private func unregisterFromBackFromBackground() {
        if(registeredToBackgroundEvents) {
            NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self,
            name: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)
            registeredToBackgroundEvents = false
        }

    }
    
    @objc func viewDidBecomeActive(){
        MyApp.showLoadingDialog = true
        MyApp.writeLog("SPI_SplashScreen|","viewDidBecomeActive() removeObserver")
        unregisterFromBackFromBackground()
        
        MyApp.writeLog("SPI_SplashScreen|","viewDidBecomeActive()->jumpToWelcomeScreen()")
        jumpToWelcomeScreen()
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()
        MyApp.currentUIViewController = self
        
        let registry = PKPushRegistry(queue: nil)
        registry.delegate = self
        registry.desiredPushTypes = [PKPushType.voIP]        

    }
    
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
        MyApp.currentUIViewController = self
        
    }
    
    
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        unregisterFromBackFromBackground()
    }  
    
    func providerDidReset(_ provider: CXProvider) {
        
        MyApp.writeLog(TAG, "providerDidReset")
    }

    func provider(_ provider: CXProvider, perform action: CXAnswerCallAction) {
        action.fulfill()
        MyApp.writeLog(TAG, "answer call action")

    }

    func provider(_ provider: CXProvider, perform action: CXEndCallAction) {
        action.fulfill()
        MyApp.writeLog(TAG, "end call action")
    }

    func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didUpdate pushCredentials: PKPushCredentials, for type: PKPushType) {
        
        MyApp.writeLog(TAG, "push registry didUpdate")
        MyApp.writeLog(TAG, pushCredentials.token.map { String(format: "%02.2hhx", $0) }.joined())
        print(pushCredentials.token.map { String(format: "%02.2hhx", $0) }.joined())
    }

    func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didReceiveIncomingPushWith payload: PKPushPayload, for type: PKPushType, completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
        
        MyApp.writeLog(TAG, "push registry didReceiveIncomingPushWith")

        
        let config = CXProviderConfiguration(localizedName: "My App")
        config.includesCallsInRecents = false
        config.supportsVideo = true
        let provider = CXProvider(configuration: config)
        provider.setDelegate(self, queue: nil)
        let update = CXCallUpdate()
        update.remoteHandle = CXHandle(type: .generic, value: "Someone")
        update.hasVideo = true
        provider.reportNewIncomingCall(with: UUID(), update: update, completion: { error in })
        
    }
    
}
```

Actually, when I write these codes in command line (terminal), test notifications come to me.

```
curl -v -d '{"aps":{"alert":"hello"}}' --http2 --cert YeniCallKit.pem:202148 https://api.development.push.apple.com/3/device/177e7861396ad0256886673d1efb3c82d5adb54e86dc5cfd781356c1672cfa07
```

I want to receive background calls that when app is closed or iphone is locked. So anyone can help me on this issue?

Comment: You need to receive the incoming VoIP push and call the CallKit to notify the incoming call

Comment: I know, but I dont know how to do?

Comment: @SmartPerson are you found any solution for your problem.